# Android - WCF Service - JSON - not working

Tags: android, json, wcf

i am intern in an app consultancy company and  i've been asked to make an ANDROID app that gets/sends some JSON data from a database using WCF Services, all i could achieve is to get connected with the url, but i get an error while parsing the data (although i think the petition didn't even reach the database).

My problem is that i don't know if it's because the code is wrong or because i don't log into the database correctly.

It requieres an user and password because the app is supposed to get/send the data from specific users from the database.

I will drop here the whole code and mark the point i get stuck at with some ***

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_clientes);


    btnpost = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnpost);
    btnpost.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://webservice1/RegistroHorario/WCFJsonRegistroHorario.svc/GetHorasDia/rcm?fecha=01/27/2014");
        }
    });
}
private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... urls) {



        return POST(urls[0]);
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
public static JSONArray POST(String url){

    InputStream is = null;
    String result ="";


    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usuario","rcm"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contraseña","password"));

    //http post
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);


        httppost.setHeader("charset", "utf-8");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.w("OK", "CONECTED----------------------------------");

                    *************THIS IS THE POINT IM STUCK AT *****************

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        return null;
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{            
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new IputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),10);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
        Log.w("OK", " CONVERTED---------------------------------");
    }catch(Exception e){
        //textView.setText("Error2: "+e.toString());
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    //parse json data
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);       
        //JArray = new JSONParser(result);
        Log.w("OK", " PERFECT -------------------------------");
        return jArray;
    }catch(JSONException e){
        //textView.setText("Error3: "+e.toString());
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

After log says "CONNECTED" i get this error:
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value 401 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONArray

I recieved 0 information from the company, all they gave me is a list of WCF URL petitions for each data required ...

I am quite lost in this JSON matter and WCF service petitions aswell, can't find any working tutorials so any info given will be great  ...

Thank you very much